# Why are there multiple versions of the date time controls in Office UI Fabric?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

There is for example a DatePicker and a Calendar control in the main package (`office-ui-fabric-react`) and in the date-time package as well (installed as `@uifabric/date-time`). Both APIs seem to be nearly identical, but differ in some properties. For example in Calendar the `calendarDayProps` property (requested in [this issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/10323)) is missing in the main package, but only available in the date-time package. I only found this out by searching through the github issues, because there is no official documentation available for the date-time package. The [documentation page available](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/calendar) only refers to the main package version.

On the other hand, in the already closed issue, it is nowhere mentioned, that this fix only applies to the date-time package version, as if this should be clear somehow. I feel that I missed some information.

So what's the point here? Will the date-time package version at some point in time replace the main package version? Are they intended to be used interchangeably? Why is there no documentation on this? I'm really confused ...

Comment: Take a look at the [Card](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/card) component's description. 

"This component is experimental and not yet importable from the office-ui-fabric-react package. Instead, import from the @uifabric/react-cards package."

I guess they can introduce breaking changes in separate packages more easily and when they are ready for the core package, they will be merged into it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint. That makes sense. However, I hope there will be kind of an official statement here.